# Python cmd and do_shell (!) implementation, can I use the shell to loop through python commands?

Tags: python, bash, shell, cmd

So I'm creating a command line program using python and the cmd module which gives you an interactive prompt to which you can define commands and it has support for help and whatnot.

Lots of fun. One of the built in commands is "!" which maps to a defined function called "do_shell" and in conjunction with "import.os" you can run normal command line... commands.

So, if I'm running python from bash and am in a python interactive prompt and type `! clear`, it'll run the bash command `clear` and clear the screen. (Same with windows but with `cls`). Otherwise, the interactive prompt simply runs commands you define for it.

Say I have defined a command

```
def do_greet(self,line)

    print "Welcome to the interactive prompt user\n"
```

ANYWAY...

Question: Can I use this implementation of "do shell" to reverse up a level and call a defined python command? Say, could I do something like this, from the python interactive prompt

```
! (for i in {1..5}; do greet; done)
```

For the record, the for loop works just fine, obviously "greet" does not. And I don't know what the correct syntax would be for that, if it was possible.

to end up with an output of

```
Welcome to the interactive prompt user
Welcome to the interactive prompt user
Welcome to the interactive prompt user
Welcome to the interactive prompt user
Welcome to the interactive prompt user
```

Please tell me this is possible.... please tell me I can utilize bash's loops and crap without having to explicitly define them in my command prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep! It's possible! Your Python function will have to change though, as there is an implicit return of value `None` when printing to the console.

Your Python function should look like this:

```
def do_greet(self,line):

    return "Welcome to the interactive prompt user\n"
```

In Bash (and CMD), commands are run from Python like so:

```
python -c "import filename; print(do_greet(argument1, argument2))"
```

Filename is just the name of the file, without the .py extension. Make sure you're in the right directory and Python3 is in your environment variables.

To run this as a for loop in Bash, it'll look like this:

```
$ for i in {1..5}; do python -c "import filename; print(filename.do_greet(arg1, arg2))"; done
```

If you're using Python2, it should look the same, except the print statement won't have parentheses:

```
$ for i in {1..5}; do python -c "import filename; print filename.do_greet(arg1, arg2)"; done
```

Comment: Are you freaking kidding me. This was a complete longshot. Just a note. Originally the "do_greet" definition was inside the console class, but in order for your solution to work it has to be in the main program, not inside a class or so. Also when I run it I get two things printed, "None" is printed followed by what I actually wanted to print. Not sure if I care about that or not. It would be nice if "None" didn't print though.

With that said, I found a way to emulate loops in the cmd module. You can simply edit the self.cmdqueue list to effectively loop through whatever you want.

Comment: Also, by having the "do_greet" function in the main body of the program, it exposes the rest of my functions to this... method and anyone willing to use it. I'll have to think of a way around that.

Comment: In case it's not obvious, this restates the last paragraph of my answer, without the caveats (that this will run the function in a separate subprocess, etc)

Comment: The requirement to `return` something for the caller to print isn't strictly necessary, though it's arguably an architectural improvement.

Comment: Looks like both our answers were written an hour ago, so I can only assume that you had submitted yours right before I submitted mine. With that being said, I think the question was very ambiguously worded, so I answered with the available information I had.

Comment: [14 minutes earlier](/posts/51345198/timeline#answer_51345469) actually but I guess you really didn't see mine before you answered. Funny how they are similar yet different.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no simple way for Bash to execute a Python function from within the Python program which defines this function.

Implementing flow control in your Python shell seems much more straightforward than managing to somehow reuse just those parts of Bash.

If you are exposing your own Python functions to the user anyway, why not go all the way and pass the user's command to Python's `eval()` function?

On the other hand, with some clever plumbing you could define `greet` in Bash as a function which runs `python -c 'import sys, yourshell; yourshell.do_greet(*sys.argv[1:])'` though this obviously runs a new (subprocess of a) subprocess, so it won't have access to the internals of your currently running Python shell.

Comment: Yeah after I messed around a bit with the other answer, (and went to bed) I realized that doing it this way wouldn't have access to the data from the main program, and that somewhat defeats the point. I suppose I could output the variables to disk then read them again in any function that's called...

Comment: Thanks for the help from both of you, it gave me ideas! If I could mark both as answers I would.

Comment: I tried... I don't have enough... reputation? Sorry :(

Comment: Sure, no problem.